# Window Functions not supported in room database after having sqlite version 3.28.0?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

i'm having sqlite version 3.28.0 and using room database but not able to use Window Functions

```
 android {
   ....
  compileSdkVersion 30
  buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
       .....
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
    }
 }
```

In API Level 30 we have sqlite version 3.28 so why room is not supporting Window Functions after having sqlite version 3.28?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary